# Cache Images from Json

Tags: json, swift, xcode, image

Hey at the Moment I'm trying to cache images from a URL that I parse from .Json in Swift. I followed this guide to parse and save my Json data: https://medium.com/@sdrzn/networking-and-persistence-with-json-in-swift-4-c400ecab402d.

I know that I could use base64 instead of the URL but I think it's not the best way to do it, cause base64 needs more space and I would have like base64 code all over my .json.

So is there a way to cache the Images and use the URL from Json to call the cached Images? Or should I just use the base64 method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about saving images to Application Support Folder and getting it by URL?

Comment: Possibly you can use any third Party for this like SDWebImage.For That please refer the documentation of it https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @Raymond How can I understand, just saving them to ApplicationSupportFolder.. I'm new to swift and not sure how this works. Maybe you have an example for me.